# What is the speed difference between cross platform HTML5 games and native mobile games?

Tags: unity, android, ios, html5, windows-phone-8

Microsoft is advertising and promoting cross platform HTML5 game development. I am thinking of creating a simple 2D side scroller game and I am trying to decide what engine should I use for creating it. I am trying to understand if there is a big difference between developping once in Unity and exporting to different platforms or simply develop it once in HTML5 in Visual Studio and publish it everywhere.
What are the drawbacks and benefits for each? Is there any speed/lag difference? 
any tips are useful

Comment: Performance comparisons between different technologies are harder than it seems. Different technologies have different bottlenecks in different places, and depending on how exactly you use them you can get vastly different results. When it comes to HTML5, you also have to keep in mind that different web browsers have different implementations which also behave differently.

Comment: I am talking about an HTML5 application not a page that you will open in your browser. Like with Construct 2 for example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference between html5 games and native games is a vast discussion, one that im not going to be able to answer in just one post.

So the closest thing i can come to a straight answer is : **It depends on the game.**

This stems from that both technologies are fairly new, and growing exponentially. As far as I know, no game studio have tried making the same game on both platforms, or at least not with publicly displaying the results.

And with HTML5 growing stronger each time i hear about it, and Unity playing with fully integrating WebGL in their engine, you can be assured that great things are in the horizon.

But one thing seems to be set at the moment:

- **HTML5 games** seems to be faster to build in, but have some hard cielings in terms of memory and scene handling.
- **Native games** have much more direct control of what is being allocated, deallocated and used, but suffer greatly in that it takes longer time to develop.

I guess "which platform to use" can not be answered for all games. Are you building a turn based trading game, I would definitely suggest to start in HTML5, at least for prototyping. Making a multiplayer fastpaced first person shooter, I would suggest that you go straight to native, since the range of network handling can be much more detailed and lag would cost a lot in the game experience.

But since HTML5 for the most part is faster to craft in, I would recommend building a prototype in HTML5 and show it to some developers. That should give you some solid feedback in what the client needs to carry, and which approach would be the smartest.

You might also find this discussion interesting : [HTML5 mobile game development vs. native game apps](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/19850/html5-mobile-game-development-vs-native-game-apps?rq=1)

**In your case:**

A simple sidescroller would be good for both platforms. I would try and weigh puzzlesolving vs action on a scale to figure out which option to pick.

In my experience, input lag has been an issue with some HTML5, especially on certain mobile devices. So if you are strong on action (especially actions that involve combos or fast reactions) the "safest" would be to go native.

But if you just want to make the game, and have people playing it as early as possible (and hopefully grow it from there) I would recommend building it in HTML5.

But in the end, it's all about the user experience.